# django social authentication через facebook

Tags: python, django, api, facebook, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте.

Нужно сделать регистрацию через `facebook` используя `django-rest-framework`. Для этой цели я использую [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) и [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). В [документации](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional) есть следующая инструкция.

settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth'
    ...,
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    ...,
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',

)
```

views:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns += [
    ...,
    url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login')
]
```

В итоге получается такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При регистрации приложения в `Facebook` я получил `App ID` и `App Secret`.

Но где взять этот `Acces token` и `Code` ?

Когда я вижу аналогичные кнопки в чьих-то приложениях, то `acces_token` есть в ссылке самой кнопки, но я не понимаю, где он генерится.

Кто-нибудь может объяснить механизм, как вся эта штуковина работает ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передать нужно `access`_token и `userID`, который возвращает в `response` функция FB.login:

```
FB.login(function(response):
    console.log(response)
    accessToken = response['authResponse'].accessToken
    userID = response['authResponse'].userID
```

И затем эти данные нужно передать на сервер, например так:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/facebook/",
     method: "post",
     data: {
         "access_token": accessToken,
         "code": userID
     }
```

а в ответе, сервер бекенд возвращает `token`, соответсвтующий данному пользователю.